# Only highlight selected row using Bootstrap, but now my whole rows are highlighting

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

```
<tr ng-repeat="player in players.items" 
    ng-click="SetSelectedItem(player)" 
    ng-class={'selected':SetSelectedItem}>
   <td>{{player.Name}}</td>
   <td>{{player.Id}} </td>
   <td>{{player.Surname}} </td>
</tr>
```

I am using CSS which is making my bg of row as red but it is applicable for every row, through ng-click i am able to select particular row but I need to highlight only the selected row

Comment: I didn't get you. can u please explain? or code?

Comment: setSelectedItem must be indual for every row. ex : ng-class={'selected':tracker.SetSelectedItem}

Comment: No its not working :(

Comment: What additional information you need..??

Answer (score 1):

I hope it may help you:-
CSS:

```
tr.red{
        background-color: red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="myctrl">
    <table>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="player in players" ng-click="togglered(player)" ng-class="{'red':tracker.isRed}">
            <td>{{player.Name}}</td>
            <td>{{player.Id}} </td>
            <td>{{player.Surname}} </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Script:

```
angular.module('myapp',[])
            .controller('myctrl',function($scope){
                $scope.red = false;
                $scope.togglered  =  function(player){
                    player.isRed = ! player.isRed;
                };
                $scope.players =[
                    {'Name':'xyz','Id':2,'Surname':1,isRed:true},
                    {'Name':'abc','Id':4,'Surname':2,isRed:false},
                    {'Name':'klm','Id':6,'Surname':3,isRed:false},
                    {'Name':'yrt','Id':9,'Surname':4,isRed:true}
                ];

            });
```

[View in Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8AG83S4PIMblr424SPus)

Comment: I Simply did this,                                                                 <tr ng-repeat="tracker in trackers.items" ng-click="SetSelectedItem(tracker,$index)" ng-class="{'selected':$index == selectedRow}">
                    <td>{{$index}}</td>
                    <td>{{tracker.ProjectName}}</td>

Comment: And in App.js                                                       $scope.SetSelectedItem = function (tracker, index) {
        $scope.selectedRow = null;
            $scope.selectedRow = index; }

Comment: i think your solution is more efficient.

Comment: but why 'tracker' is passed in SetSelectedItem.. I don't understand it.

Comment: tracker is passed to show all data in edit dialog box